# redirect page after axios success login - reactJS

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony

I am trying to create a login page with react. I submit the form and send data to the server (PHP/Symfony) where I run login logic and return JSON object with success or error data.
Then if user data is right and login is ok, I need to redirect him to another page. I am using react `state.`

**LoginComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

class LoginComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      errors: {},
      login:'',
      password:'',
      fireRedirect: false
    };

    this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
  }

  processForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const login = this.state.login;
    const password = this.state.password;
    //TODO validation

    const formData = { login:login, password:password };

    axios.post('http://myweburl.org/app/web/login', formData, { headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} })
      .then((response) => {

        if(response.data.success) {
          this.setState({ fireRedirect: true })
        }else if(response.data.error){
            this.setState({
            errors:response.data.error
          });
        }
      });
  }

  handleLoginChange(e) {
    this.setState({login: e.target.value});
  }

  handlePasswordChange(e) {
    this.setState({password: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    //const { fireRedirect } = this.state;
    if(this.state.fireRedirect) {
        return <Redirect to={'/obligation'}/>
    }

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="full-content">
            <div className="login-page">
              <div className="egz-logo"><img src={`/img/logo.png`} alt="MyEGZ" title="MyEGZ"/></div>
              <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.processForm}>
                <div className="login-block">
                  <input type="text" name="login" value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleLoginChange.bind(this)} placeholder="login" id="client-login"/>
                </div>
                <div className="login-block">
                  <input type="password" autoComplete="off" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)} placeholder="mot de passe" id="client-pwd"/>
                </div>
                <div className="login-block">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="client-remember-me"/>
                  <label>Se souvenire de moi</label>
                </div>
                <div className="login-button-block">
                  <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" value="Connexion"/>
                  <div >
                    <Link key="forgot-pwd" to={`/login/forgetpassword`}>
                      mot de passe oubile
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import './index.css';
import { Router,Route } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import Obligation from './components/obligation/ObligationComponent';
import Contacts from './components/contacts/ContactComponent';
import ContactPage from './components/contacts/ContactPage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginComponent';
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

function auth() {

  axios.post('http://myweburl.org/app/web/checkLogin', { headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      if(response.data.success){
        return true;
      }else if(response.data.error){
        return false;
      }
    });

};

const isAuthorized = auth();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => <LoginPage isAuthorized={isAuthorized} />} />
        <Route path="/obligation" component={() => <Obligation title="Obligations légales" isAuthorized={isAuthorized} style="home-header"/> }/>
        <Route path='/contacts' component={() => <Contacts title="Contacts" isAuthorized={isAuthorized} style="contact-header" />} />
        <Route path="/contact/:id" component={() => <ContactPage isAuthorized={isAuthorized} />}/>
      </div>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When I submit form with right data, it returns success with correct data
{"success":1,"data":{"clients_id":"2"}}
and the print response data in loginComponent ajax success it also returns me this -

> console.log(response.data.success,this.state.fireRedirect);
>
> 1 true

But redirect is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is how i usually do my api calls.

```
axios
                .post("/yourApiEnd", {
                    accounts: this.accounts
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    const status = response.status;
                    //redirect logic
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                            window.location = "/script" 
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in **LoginComponent.js** you have already used the state to trigger when successful login happens.
now you need to trigger that at code .
You can add a statement at the render to trigger the redirect

```
...  
return (
      <div className="wrapper">
{this.state.fireRedirect && <Redirect to="location" />}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Redirect to='/obligation'/>
```

or

```
<Redirect to={this.props.someVar}/>
```

or

```
<Redirect to={something}/>
```

but you used curly braces for js resolving and provided string in them.